# Update List Title automatically every year

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a list which has a name lets say "2019 Something" and my plan is to make this title of the list update every year on it's own without the next after it being changed.

Is there a way to update the year based on a calculation or on a specific date every year. It should be automated as it is the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Create timer job with schedule based on the year change or
   running periodically.
2. Also you can write workflows which will update the
   title of the list.